# What's wrong with this code in c++ involving sorting of an array of objects?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class student
{
    public:
    string s;
    int age;
};

istream& operator >>(istream& in, student& val) 
{
    return in >> val.s >> val.age;
}
bool valuecmp(student & a, student & b)
{
    return a.s < b.s;
}

int main (void)
{
    student a[5];

    fstream myfile; 
    myfile.open("a1.txt",ios::in);
    int i = 0;

    for (string line; getline(myfile, line);) 
    {
        istringstream stream(line);
        student person;
        stream >> person;
        a[i] = person;
        cout<<a[i].s<<a[i].age<<"\n";
        i++;
    }
    sort(a,a+2,valuecmp);
    for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
    {
        cout<<a[i].s<<a[i].age<<"\n";
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

What I am trying to do is basically reading a file containing the objects information in different rows. I am then trying to sort those objects according to the value of the string s. However, this code shows an error. Why is this happening?

Error: ( It is a very big one, adding a part of it )

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/algorithm:62:0,
             from faltu1.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of '_RandomAccessIterator   std::__unguarded_partition(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = student*; _Tp = student; _Compare = bool (*)(student&, student&)]':
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h:2296:78:   required from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare)   [with _RandomAccessIterator = student*; _Compare = bool (*)(student&, student&)]'
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what the error is? Does it happen when compiling, or when running?

Comment: First figure out if the problem is in the reading in, or in the sorting.

Comment: Age is a signed int, that's one thing that's wrong... :)

Comment: I can see several things that are wrong with this code, but unless you tell us what the error is, it's going to be hard to help you.

Comment: No, problem is in compiling. And the problem is happening in the sorting part. I am sure of that because without that, it is working perfectly.

Comment: And the error that comes up is a very big one. I am editing the original post for the part of error. :)

Comment: Please include at least the last line of the error (after all the `required from` lines), since that gives the actual error message; and the line before, which indicates which line of your code caused the error. It would be best to include all of it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you:

1. Remove a raw fixed-size array and use `std::vector<student>` or
   `std::list<student>`, e.g. `std::vector<student> a;`
2. Replace `a[i] = person;` with `a.emplace_back(std::move(person));`
3. Sort ranges: `sort(a.begin(),a.end(),valuecmp);`
4. Change the signature of your comparing function to accept `const student&` args

   `bool valuecmp(const student & a, const student& b)`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to post the descriptive part of the error:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘student&’ from expression 
    of type ‘const student’
    while (__comp(*__first, __pivot))
```

indicating that the `sort` algorithm is trying to pass a `const` argument to your comparator, which incorrectly takes its arguments as non-const references.

To fix it, make the arguments `const`:

```
bool valuecmp(student const & a, student const & b)
```